# Determine file extension for image urls

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a reliable and fast way to determine the file extension of an image url? THere are a few options I see but none of them work consistently for images of the below format

```
https://cdn-image.blay.com/sites/default/files/styles/1600x1000/public/images/12.jpg?itok=e-zA1T
```

I have tried:

```
new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(url)
```

Results in the generic "application/octet-stream" in which case I use the below two:

```
Files.getFileExtension
FilenameUtils.getExtension
```

I would like to avoid regex when possible so is there another utility that properly gets past links that have args (.jpeg?blahblah). I would also like to avoid downloading the image or connection to the url in anyway as this should be a performant call

Comment: you could check the extension, but the extension listed might not match the images actual extension. It is trivial to change a filename

Comment: @JohnKane That would be fine. Let's assume we trust the url completely and would just like to extract the url extension such as .jpg or .png from any given link. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: you could just parse it out if you do not want to use a regex using substring(str.lastIndexOf('.'),str.length); or something similar if your format will not change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can trust that the URLs are not malformed, how about this:

```
FilenameUtils.getExtension(URI.create(url).getPath())
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar

final String filePath = Paths.get(new URI(url).getPath()).getFileName().toString();

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just look at the file extension in the URL? so that would be something like:

```
public static String getFileExtension(String url) {
    int phpChar = url.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < url.length(); i++) {
        if(url.charAt(i) == '?') {
            phpChar = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    int character = phpChar - 1;
    while(url.charAt(character) != '.') character -= 1;
    return url.substring(character + 1, phpChar);
}
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works, even with the php ? in the url.